# Find prime numbers in an interval or ELSE find all possible divisions of the non-prime number

Tags: python-3.x

What's wrong whith this code:

```
def Prime(a,b):
    for n in range(a,b):
        for x in range(a,n):
            if n % x == 0:
                print(n,"equales to",x,"*",n//x)
            else:
                break
        else:
            print(n,"is a prime number")

Prime(2,16)
```

I want to print all prime numbers in an interval, if not, print all possible divisions of that non-prime number

the output:

```
2 is a prime number
4 equales to 2 * 2
6 equales to 2 * 3
6 equales to 3 * 2
8 equales to 2 * 4
10 equales to 2 * 5
12 equales to 2 * 6
12 equales to 3 * 4
12 equales to 4 * 3
14 equales to 2 * 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for/else` statement works in such a way that only if the loop is exhausted **without reaching a `break` statement**, the `else` will be executed.

This is the opposite of what you meant I am guessing.

What I would do, is simply create a "flag" variable to check at the end of the loop. Something like:

```py
def Prime(a,b):
    for n in range(a,b):
        is_prime = True
        for x in range(a,n):
            if n % x == 0:
                is_prime = False
                print(n,"equales to",x,"*",n//x)
        if is_prime:
            print(n,"is a prime number")
```

This gives on `Prime(2,16)`:

```
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
4 equales to 2 * 2
5 is a prime number
6 equales to 2 * 3
6 equales to 3 * 2
7 is a prime number
8 equales to 2 * 4
8 equales to 4 * 2
9 equales to 3 * 3
10 equales to 2 * 5
10 equales to 5 * 2
11 is a prime number
12 equales to 2 * 6
12 equales to 3 * 4
12 equales to 4 * 3
12 equales to 6 * 2
13 is a prime number
14 equales to 2 * 7
14 equales to 7 * 2
15 equales to 3 * 5
15 equales to 5 * 3
```